# MySql REGEXP multiple words search by including specific words

Tags: php, mysql, regex, search

I have a databse with keywords coloumn

Need to search the database on the basis of query done by user.

Every keyword has word "outlet" at the end but user will only search "gul ahmad" not "gul ahmad outlet". For this i used following query and things worked fine to get results and found complete result "Gul Ahmad Outlet"

```
$sql = "SELECT keywords FROM table WHERE keywords REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)$keyword([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'";
```

Now i have 2 issues
1. If the word "outlet is in between the query words then it does not find the word. e.g if user search "kohistan lahore", database has an outlet named "kohistan outlet lahore" but it does not find the keyword in database and returns empty. How to tell database to include "outlet" in between, at the start or athe end to find and match the result.

2. if some user search "nabeel's outlet" database has it but due to " ' " this query returns empty without any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is that you can match your column values with just the first word 
of your search expression(i.e nabeel's outlet). I believe this way you will be able to cover all your scenarios.

```
select 
      * 
from `outlets` 
    where REPLACE(`name`,'\'','') regexp SUBSTRING_INDEX('nabeels outlet', ' ', 1)
```

Look at this fiddle and test yourself : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3000/21

Hope it helps.

Comment: It does not solve issue as if user search nabeels outlet nothing comes as " ' " is misunderstood......

Comment: Edited to escape apostrophes in column values.

Comment: Thanks it worked for " ' " but how i can solve " & " issue? and other issue is with regexp SUBSTRING_INDEX('nabeels outlet', ' ', 1)  only focus on first word and if we have more than 1 or 2 entries with same starting word it does not follow query and turns other resutt than desired.......... can we tell this query '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)$keyword([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)' to see if exact match can come by adding outlet in between words

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler:  `[[:<:]]$keyword[[:>:]]` -- This checks for "word boundary" instead of space or punctuation or start/end of string.  And `$keyword = "nabeel's"` should not be a problem.

Don't you want to always tack on "outlet"?

```
REGEXP "[[:<:]]$keyword[[:>:]] outlet"
```

And, yes, you *must* escape certain things, such as the quotes that will be used to quote the regex string.  PHP's `addslashes()` is one way.